# To delete a product and also delete order and orderitem if the product existed in the data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to delete a product, but it cannot be done when the product is existed in orderitem tables.

1. I need to check order items tables whether got this product or not , if existed then delete the order item.
2. Next, I need to check whether order tables still got other order items, if only got 1 orderitem that has the product, then straight delete the order.
3. After that only delete the product.

how is the sql statement with the 3 statement?

This is the example of the third statement:

**string sql = "UPDATE Artwork SET DeletedAt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE Id = @Id AND ArtistId=@ArtistId";**

This is my artwork tables

[image]

This is my order tables and orderitem tables.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach for relational integrity -- that is, being sure that `orderitems` references a valid `artwork` even when the `artwork.id` row is deleted -- is a cascading foreign key constraint:

```
alter table orderitems add constraint fk_orderitem_artworkid
    foreign key (artworkid) references artwork(id)
    on delete cascade;
```

Then when you delete a row from `artwork`, all order items will be automatically deleted.

To handle deleting orders with no order items is a bit more complicated.  For that, you might want a trigger.  However, the syntax depends on the database you are using.